# How can I highlight the highest value in each row of a table?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-statements, google-sheets-formula, max, conditional-formatting

In Google Sheets, I would like to highlight the max value in each row of a table.

I tried using conditional formatting, but without any success so far.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

custom formula is:

```
=(A1=MAX($A1:$D1))*(A1<>"")
```

[image: 0]

---

for columns:

```
=(A1=MAX(A$1:A))*(A1<>"")
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! What would be the syntax for highlighting the max number in each column instead of each row?

Comment: @CruzNunez answer updated

Answer (score 1):

For each column do the following:

```
1) Select column or range (say it is A)
2) Select conditional formatting
3) Select in "Format rules" "custom formula is"
4) Enter the formula: =A1=MAX(A$1:A$6)

Here A1 - starting cell
A6 - ending cell
```